# Straight forward way to use your own NPM package without the NPM registry

Tags: npm, package, maintainability

I want to split up the code base of several of my project into isolated package like projects. Those should be easily usable by npm but they do not seem significant enough to be published to the global npm registry.

So, my question is if there is a middle way to handling them like local provided packages and installing them with their path and publishing them in the global repository.

Concerns:

- cluttering the npm registry with packages which don't seem to be significant enough to take up the name
- the need to document and to create tests for each package seems to be too much and I would not sleep well publishing packages which are not well documented and tested
- I take up a name which might be more appropriate to be used by a more sophisticated package and maintainers

  - I still want other to be able to easily try / use this package, to see if it fits their needs

Alternatives:

- A) creating a private npm repository (with CouchDB?)

  - + is pretty much identical to the npm repository and would be easy to use
  - + the versioning is identical just pure semver lookup
  - - every user needs to set up this repository if they want to use this package or need it as a child dependency in their (public npm) package (even though this is unlikely)
  - - Need to invest time into setting it up and maintaining it
- B) Using my username npm namespace

  - + would solve pretty much every problem
  - - namespaces seem to be meant for projects and its sub packages which wouldn't be the case for my packages since their only connection is the creator
  - - it seems arrogant to prefix your packages with your name, like you are tagging it with a big sign *THIS WAS DONE BY ME*
- C) Using GitHub with a special detached branch which contains the (tagged) releases

  - + you could use it like the global npm repository since the npm resolving strategy allows the repository url with a semver range in place of the version
  - - special case which is bound to break
  - - GitHub is not meant to provide npm packages, about no developer expects a git url instead of the versionrange, tools and firewalls might have problem with this
  - - workflow is really not meant this way neither for git nor for npm
- D) using a local package and install package by its path

  - + easy to setup and use
  - - no version management
  - - build steps must be done manually beforehand
  - - can not publish packages depending on those packages
  - - all dependencies have to be installed locally
- E) making those packages more useful, implementing edge cases, writing documentation and testing the whole package

  - + would resolve about all problems
  - - ALOT of extra work, primarily thinking about edge cases and giving the developer a good api
  - - sometimes you can't really get the name for you package (it collides with other) which results in weird
  - - it is your responsibility, you have to maintain it, be responsible (test it well, edge cases)
  - - cluttering of the npm repository

So those are all the alternatives which came to mind when I tried to find a solution. Please leave a comment / answer if you have another idea or maybe you can remove / reduce the importance of those contra points.

Maybe you could include your own experience, so I get a better view for the whole problem.

Currently I would just try to make the package more helpful to the greater majority but this does not work in all cases.

Thank you all for your time!

Comment: 1: Not sure if firewalls are a big problem with GitHub if used with HTTPS. CocoaPods regularly hosts source from there. 2: Have you considered git submodule?

Answer (score 1):

Installing from git is pretty standard feature in package managers. [npm doesn't have Github-support](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install), it's generic support for any git repo. Unless you can find some discussion about deprecating it from npm, I'd not worry about it. It's used internally in many companies for private packages.

Of course, there is still some trade offs: build artifacts and maybe a bit more clumsy workflow. Things like `npm outdated` doesn't understand git semver. For build artifacts, I have seen many projects to commit them to master branch to support direct git-install. If you look around older open source projects for example, that's the case quite often.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! Are there any other drawbacks beside the versioning and the deploy workflow? Do you have some good writeup about the usage with git which you could share? I would really like to read some more about this option since I have no clue about the drawbacks and pitfalls.

Answer (score 1):

We went for a private repository with [verdaccio](https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio) running in a docker container, which is very similar to version A. It took some setup, but for our developers all it took was a single npm command to add the private repo "in front of" npm for all packages of the namespace we created. Granted, our packages are project specific, but in a private repository that does not really matter either way, does it?

We considered the local package option at first, but the drawbacks were just too big for us, even if it's very easy to setup.

I'm not sure this helps, but this is at least the setup we decided upon when we had the same issue a few months ago.

Comment: Hey thank you for you answer! We recently used verdaccio for a project, but wouldn't this prevent you from using this package in other public (in the global registry) packages? For example, with the npm name prefix or git approach you could still use them in global packages.

Comment: Yes, if I understand your point correctly, that would be the case. However, if that's the case the very fact you have or are planning to have, dependencies on your packages very much justifies the approach of publishing it to the global registry or no? Maybe it's worth just putting a bit more time into the namespace name instead, and publish it after all?